# What's the simple way of mixing signed-ness calculation in zig?

Tags: zig

Zig insists a strict checking on integer signedness mixing, which is great, and it enforces programmers to really see what's happening.

But then what in C looks like

```c
uint64_t a = 100;
int32_t b = 42;
uint64_t c = a + b;
```

has to be like this in Zig:

```
var a: u64 = 100;
var b: i32 = 42;
var c = if (b >= 0) a + @bitCast(u32, b) else a - @bitCast(u32, -b);
```

So is this the best we can have? Or are there more elegant ways of putting it?

Comment: Why do you use `@bitCast` and not `@intCast`?

Answer (score 1):

The best general solution to this problem is to *avoid* mixing signed and unsigned integer types in calculations. When you find this problem appearing in a program, look to program design improvements first to avoid the situation.

These types of conversions always depend on context. Since in this case the value of `a` will fit in an `i32` and it seems that OP is interested in cases where `b` may be negative, a more "elegant" solution might be to cast `a` to `i32`. This allows correct addition with any `i32` value for `b` (so long as `a` will in fact fit in an `i32`). In general when you *must* do some mixed signed/unsigned integer arithmetic it is probably better to cast unsigned types to signed types when possible.

For more safety, cast to a *wider* signed type when possible. Since a `u64` will fit into an `i128`, you can cast both values to `i128` safely and then perform the arithmetic. In Zig addition invokes [peer type resolution](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#Peer-Type-Resolution) which finds a common type for the operands, so there is no need to explicitly cast the `i32` to the wider `i128` type.

It would also be better to use [`@intCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#intCast) which is specifically for casting between integer types. The `@intCast` built-in provides runtime safety checks (which may be disabled). When `@intCast` attempts to convert a value which is out of range of the destination type the program will crash with a stack trace. This is better than using `@bitCast` which can provide no such safety checks.

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() void {
    var a: u64 = 100;
    var b: i32 = 42;
    var c: i32 = -42;

    var aPlus_b = @intCast(i32, a) + b;  // 100 will fit in `i32`
    var aPlus_c = @intCast(i128, a) + c; // any `u64` will fit in `i128`

    std.debug.print("{} + {} = {}: {}\n", .{ a, b, aPlus_b, @TypeOf(aPlus_b) });
    std.debug.print("{} + {} = {}: {}\n", .{ a, c, aPlus_c, @TypeOf(aPlus_c) });
}
```

Program output:

```
100 + 42 = 142: i32
100 + -42 = 58: i128
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one:

```
var c = @addWithOverflow(a, @bitCast(u32, b))[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

zig's translate-c command turns it into:

```
var a: u64 = 100;
var b: i32 = 42;
var c: u64 = a +% @bitCast(u64, @as(c_longlong, b));
```